# Conditional and grouped mutate dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Lets say I have the following data of sock increase per drawer

```
>socks
year  drawer_nbr  sock_total
1990    1           2
1991    1           2
1990    2           3
1991    2           4
1990    3           2
1991    3           1
```

I would like to have a binary variable that identifies if the socks have increased in each drawer. 1 if they increased and 0 if not. The result would be

```
>socks
drawer_nbr  growth
  <dbl>     <factor>
    1          0  
    2          1
    3          0
```

I am getting stuck on comparing `sock_total` of one year vs `sock_total` of another year. I know that I need to use `dplyr::summaries()`, but I am having difficulty with what goes inside that function.

Comment: Are you only working with two years of data?

Comment: @Alex P yes, there are only 2 years at most.

Comment: Here is another option `socks %>% arrange(drawer_nbr, year) %>% group_by(drawer_nbr) %>% summarise(growth = +(diff(sock_total) > 0))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are comparing year 1991 with 1990, you can do:

```
socks %>% 
    group_by(drawer_nbr) %>% 
    summarise(growth = +(sock_total[year == 1991] - sock_total[year == 1990] > 0))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  drawer_nbr growth
#       <int>  <int>
#1          1      0
#2          2      1
#3          3      0
```

Comment: What is the `+` for?

Comment: It's a short hand for converting boolean values to numeric with `TRUE` to 1, `FALSE` to 0.

Comment: You can add a filter after `group_by` to filter out groups that don't have both years data. `socks %>% group_by(drawer_nbr) %>% filter(all(c(1990, 1991) %in% year)) %>% summarise(growth = +(sock_total[year == 1991] - sock_total[year == 1990] > 0))`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a mix of `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

socks %>%
  group_by(drawer_nbr) %>% 
  spread(year, sock_total) %>%
  mutate(growth = `1991` - `1990`)
```

Or if you only wanted growth to be binary:

```
socks %>%
  group_by(drawer_nbr) %>% 
  spread(year, sock_total) %>%
  mutate(growth = ifelse((`1991` - `1990`) > 0,
                         1, 0))
```